# Image not showing in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am new to React JS. I was building a login page and my CSS was working fine, with the background image showing. However, as I added more functionalities, the image stopped showing, but there is no error.

Here is my code for image in Login.css

```css
body {
  background-image: url("E:\React js\chatbot\public\images\image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Does everyone viewing the webpage have an E: drive mapped to the same location as you? Generally you want to URL to be a relative URL from the CSS file to the image.